# Whom is Shiki talking to in the dream where he meets a serial killer (in the Kohaku route)?

Tags: tsukihime

In *Tsukihime*'s Kohaku route, Shiki falls asleep and has a "dream" after the welcoming party.

In it, he (or SHIKI) encounters another serial killer. They drink coffee bought from a vending machine together and have a conversation. Afterwards, the other killer decides to leave the city, believing that there would be trouble if the city had two serial killers.

I'm wondering who this other person was, and if they, too, were sent by the same person who sent Nrvnqsr Chaos to kill Arcueid Brunestud. (I remember reading about it the other day, but I can't remember who; I know for sure it wasn't Roa.)

Comment: by chance... are they having a conversation in a park about boxing?

Comment: @Krazer i can't remember, all i remember is they get a drink from a nearby vending machine, are in the park at some point and they talked about stuff before the unknown person left, i waited until i saw every scene in Kagetsu Tohya just in case if it was explained in that

Comment: Can you please be a bit more specific? At least be sure which route you're talking about and if possible, the scene that precedes and/or fo;lows the one you're describing. There's a lot of dialogue and text to go through...

Comment: Is this the scene at the end [here](http://lparchive.org/Tsukihime/Update%20145/)? The playthrough says that it's from the Kohaku route. (I vaguely remember this being in the Hisui route, which I just played through, but I could be wrong, seeing as I didn't pay extremely close attention and also skipped scenes I'd read before.)

Comment: @Maroon yes that's the scene. might explain why I kept missing it when I tried to look for it as I wasn't checking though the welcoming party scene (since the route splitting is further on)

Comment: @Memor-X: it looks like the split is _at_ the welcoming party scene, but up to the events after the party, everything is mostly the same. I also thought it was later on though, but I remembered that the scene involved cans of coffee and so just searched for "coffee" in the playthrough.

Comment: I edited in to specify the scene. I'm still unsure as to whether this also appears in the Hisui route (per my earlier comment), and I haven't played the Akiha one yet, but since it seems to definitely come up in the Kohaku route, I'm just leaving that for now so that otherpeople can locate it.

Comment: @Maroon thanks, i was going to do that myself when i got on. it may be on both routes as there is more or less 3 "stories" with Hisui's and Kohaku's Route following a similar story like how Arcuied's and Ceil's did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tohno Shiki (who is really Nanaya Shiki) is meeting with Tohno Shiki (who is really Tohno Shiki) in that scene. They don't recognize each other.

> SHIKI catches a drugged Shiki going berserk and killing some people in a back alley. Both have coffee on a park bench while discussing life and how they both fit into the world, and joking with each other like friends. SHIKI even points that Shiki reminds him of his precious childhood friend, not realizing that he is the same person. In the end, SHIKI does try to start a fight, but Shiki tells him that he's superior in a fight to the death. Surprisingly, he agrees with him, and decides to give up and leave town for good.

Source: http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/SHIKI_Tohno#Kohaku.27s_route